# How can I get standart background image of UI elements in iOS?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I need help with next question. I create custom UI element, like UIAlertView. But I need to make it look like standart UIAlertView. But I can't find png file for standart background. Maybe, I can somehow get it from resources of UIAlertView?
Thanks.

Comment: so why not use standard UIAlertView???

Comment: I know, it's strange, but I need more specific logic for it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what your logic can be handled by standard UIAlertView

Comment: @user1774316 well then you need to open up Photoshop and start painting your custom UIAlertView, but i think you should have very good reason for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that the part of the UI element you are referring to is drawn and no image is used, this is typical. 
If you are looking for something similar you can maybe take a look at [this github project](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView/blob/master/TSAlertView/TSAlertViewBackground2.png)

Hope this will help